# Next.js use localstorage problem with SSR

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have the following custom hook which stores data in the localstorage:

```jsx
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const useLocalStorage = (key, initialValue) => {
  const initialize = (key) => {
    try {
      const item = localStorage.getItem(key);
      if (item && item !== "undefined") {
        return JSON.parse(item);
      }

      localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(initialValue));
      return initialValue;
    } catch {
      return initialValue;
    }
  };

  const [state, setState] = useState(() => initialize(key)); // problem is here

  const setValue = useCallback(
    (value) => {
      try {
        const valueToStore = value instanceof Function ? value(storedValue) : value;
        setState(valueToStore);
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(valueToStore));
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    },
    [key, setState]
  );

  const remove = useCallback(() => {
    try {
      localStorage.removeItem(key);
    } catch {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }, [key]);

  return [state, setValue, remove];
};
```

It shows the following problem, which i googled it and it seems it due to the fact that Nextjs tries to run the code on the server side and there is no available window object.

[image]

The problem seems to come from the line where i try to initialize the stored data:

```jsx
const [state, setState] = useState(() => initialize(key));
```

I tried to pack this logic within a useEffect so it only runs on client side, but i got the infinite loop which i couldnt solve.

Answer (score 8):

```js
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const useLocalStorage = (key, initialValue) => {
  const initialize = (key) => {
    try {
      const item = localStorage.getItem(key);
      if (item && item !== "undefined") {
        return JSON.parse(item);
      }

      localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(initialValue));
      return initialValue;
    } catch {
      return initialValue;
    }
  };

  const [state, setState] = useState(null); // problem is here

  // solution is here....
  useEffect(()=>{
    setState(initialize(key));
  },[]);

  const setValue = useCallback(
    (value) => {
      try {
        const valueToStore = value instanceof Function ? value(storedValue) : value;
        setState(valueToStore);
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(valueToStore));
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    },
    [key, setState]
  );

  const remove = useCallback(() => {
    try {
      localStorage.removeItem(key);
    } catch {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }, [key]);

  return [state, setValue, remove];
};
```

`window,localStorage,sessionStorage,etc..` are not defined on server, so accessing them on server will result as an error. Use `useEffect` to make sure that, these code will be executed on client side.

Comment: ```React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'initialize' and 'key'.``` So when i add initialzie method to the depenedncy, it says that the initialize method should use useCallback, so than i made it using that. When i add initialValue to the dependency array of useCallback, i got infinite loop.

Comment: Do not add anythinff

Comment: Is it a good practice to leave out dependency?

Comment: @J.Doe `useEffect` completely runs on client side, so you don't need to add any dependency.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies

Comment: If you want rerender then, otherwise it is completely okey

Answer (score 1):

Maybe move the initialize to inside a useEffect (useState needs to be kept outside however)

Inside the useEffect, you initialize only if `typeof window !== "undefined"`

Comment: useEffect only runs on client side, so checking the window should not needed. And it is not the problem. See the comment for the Rahul answer.

Comment: In next.js, it can run on the server during SSR, like when you are running things locally, no?

Comment: useEffect has a csr(client side rendering) mechanism, its not different if you are using in ssg or ssr pre-render

Comment: Ok, I get it now, thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me with React/NextJS :)

```html
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const isServer = typeof window === 'undefined';

export default function useLocalStorage(key, initialValue) {
  // State to store our value
  // Pass initial state function to useState so logic is only executed once
  const [storedValue, setStoredValue] = useState(() => initialValue);

  const initialize = () => {
    if (isServer) {
      return initialValue;
    }
    try {
      // Get from local storage by key
      const item = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
      // Parse stored json or if none return initialValue
      return item ? JSON.parse(item) : initialValue;
    } catch (error) {
      // If error also return initialValue
      console.log(error);
      return initialValue;
    }
  };

  /* prevents hydration error so that state is only initialized after server is defined */
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isServer) {
      setStoredValue(initialize());
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  // Return a wrapped version of useState's setter function that ...
  // ... persists the new value to localStorage.
  const setValue = (value) => {
    try {
      // Allow value to be a function so we have same API as useState
      const valueToStore =
        value instanceof Function ? value(storedValue) : value;
      // Save state
      setStoredValue(valueToStore);
      // Save to local storage
      if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(valueToStore));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // A more advanced implementation would handle the error case
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  return [storedValue, setValue];
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).