# How to implement a useLocalStorage hook in Next.js?

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, next.js, local-storage

I am trying to create a replacement of `useState` in next.js resilient to page refreshes.

One of the possible solutions that came across was to use `window.localStorage` to save and retrieve the state. That would make state persistent even after page refreshes.

I found the following implementation of a `useLocalStorage` hook for ReactJS https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/

```
function useLocalStorage(key, initialValue) {
  // State to store our value
  // Pass initial state function to useState so logic is only executed once
  const [storedValue, setStoredValue] = useState(() => {
    if (typeof window === "undefined") {
      return initialValue;
    }
    try {
      // Get from local storage by key
      const item = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
      // Parse stored json or if none return initialValue
      return item ? JSON.parse(item) : initialValue;
    } catch (error) {
      // If error also return initialValue
      console.log(error);
      return initialValue;
    }
  });
  // Return a wrapped version of useState's setter function that ...
  // ... persists the new value to localStorage.
  const setValue = (value) => {
    try {
      // Allow value to be a function so we have same API as useState
      const valueToStore =
        value instanceof Function ? value(storedValue) : value;
      // Save state
      setStoredValue(valueToStore);
      // Save to local storage
      if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
        window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(valueToStore));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // A more advanced implementation would handle the error case
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  return [storedValue, setValue];
}
```

However, it generates the following error when I use it in NextJS:

> Uncaught Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server

After a little search I found out that the `window` object doesn't exist in the (Next.js) server side and this is the possible cause of the error ([Window is not defined in Next.js React app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55151041/window-is-not-defined-in-next-js-react-app)).
A possible solution is to protect the usage of `window` with the `useEffect` hook, that only runs on the client side.

My current implementation of the `useLocalStorage` hook is

```
function useLocalStorage<T>(key: string, defaultValue: T): [T, Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>] {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<T>(defaultValue);

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      const item = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
      setValue(item ? JSON.parse(item) : defaultValue);
    }
    catch (error) {
      setValue(defaultValue);
    }
    
  }, [key, defaultValue]);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  }, [key, value]);

  return [value, setValue];
};
```

However, this time the hook doesn't always work as expected because the order of execution of the useEffect callbacks is not guaranteed. As a consequence, sometimes the state is lost.

I want to know what would be a correct implementation for this in NextJS and understand where the logic of my code is failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a useLocalStorage hook which works with next.js

```
import React, { useDebugValue, useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const useLocalStorage = <S>(
  key: string,
  initialState?: S | (() => S)
): [S, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<S>>] => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<S>(initialState as S);
  useDebugValue(state);

  useEffect(() => {
    const item = localStorage.getItem(key);
    if (item) setState(parse(item));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(state));
  }, [state]);

  return [state, setState];
};

const parse = (value: string) => {
  try {
    return JSON.parse(value);
  } catch {
    return value;
  }
};
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work any more.

Comment: @parasomnist I use this hook very regularly and it works can you describe your problem

Comment: For me the state gets reset to the default value when I reload the page

Comment: @DavidMartin the hook doesn't work in dev with reactStrictMode enabled. Do you have it enabled by any chance?

Answer (score 5):

```
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'

export default function useLocalStorage<T>(
  key: string,
  defaultValue: T
): [T, Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>] {
  const isMounted = useRef(false)
  const [value, setValue] = useState<T>(defaultValue)

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      const item = window.localStorage.getItem(key)
      if (item) {
        setValue(JSON.parse(item))
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
    return () => {
      isMounted.current = false
    }
  }, [key])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isMounted.current) {
      window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value))
    } else {
      isMounted.current = true
    }
  }, [key, value])

  return [value, setValue]
}
```

Here, `useRef` is being used to prevent the `defaultValue` getting stored in `localStorage` in first render. Basically, it skips the callback of second `useEffect` to run on first render, so initialization can complete without race condition by first `useEffect` hook.

Answer (score 2):

Markos's answer kept resetting the state on refresh for me. I added one small tweak, and that fixed the issue:

```
import React, { useDebugValue, useEffect, useState } from "react"

const useLocalStorage = <S>(
  key: string,
  initialState?: S | (() => S)
): [S, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<S>>] => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<S>(initialState as S)
  useDebugValue(state)

  useEffect(() => {
    const item = localStorage.getItem(key)
    if (item) setState(parse(item))
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (state !== initialState) {
      localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(state))
    }
  }, [state])

  return [state, setState]
}

const parse = (value: string) => {
  try {
    return JSON.parse(value)
  } catch {
    return value
  }
}

export default useLocalStorage
```

Comment: The fix is actually buggy. It may be totally valid that the value is supposed to be the initial value. Image that scenario:

initial value: A -> user changes value to B -> user changes value back to A -> wouldn't work because of `if (state !== initialState)`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the author is still relevant. But maybe someone will come in handy.
This worked for me. I replaced one `useEffect` with a function so that `useEffect` wouldn't get called uncontrollably.
The default value will be set to `useEffect`, in all other cases the `changeValue` function will be called.

```js
export const useLocalStorage = (key: string, defaultValue: any) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(defaultValue);

    const changeValue = (value) => {        
        setValue(value);
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    } 

    useEffect(() => {
        const stored = localStorage.getItem(key);

        if (!stored) {
            setValue(defaultValue);
            localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(defaultValue));
        } else {
            setValue(JSON.parse(stored));
        }
    }, [defaultValue, key]);

    return [value, changeValue]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: [Next.js use localstorage problem with SSR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68808837/next-js-use-localstorage-problem-with-ssr)

... and it didn't reset the value at every refresh unlike @MarkosTh09's solution.